# Jersery API Body Writer Issue

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I`ve been searching for an answer for this problem for a while but cant seem to find the correct solution to the problem. I have a service in which i calling the Web Resource like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/save")

public Response addPushMessage(@FormParam("key") String key, @FormParam("pid") String pid,  
                                    @FormParam("url") String url, @FormParam("message") String message) throws Throwable {
    if(key == null || key.isEmpty() || pid == null || pid.isEmpty())
            return Response.ok().entity("Error: image key and profile Id are required for push message").build();
    try{
         Date now = new Date();
         BasicDBObject pushMsg = new BasicDBObject("key", key).append("provider", pid).append("createdDate", now);
         if(url!= null)
             pushMsg.append("url", url);
         if(message != null && !message.isEmpty())
             pushMsg.append("message", message);
         pushMsg.append("status", status);
         String pushMsgId = ServiceUtil.mongo.put(GliifConstant.pushMsgCollectionName, pushMsg);

         // Notify Event manager to push events if it's PROD
         // Changed it delibrately to dev for local testing
         if(ServiceUtil.env.equalsIgnoreCase("dev")){
             PushEvent event = new PushEvent();
             event.setCreatedDate(now);
             event.setEventId(pushMsgId);
             event.setKey(key);
             event.setUrl(url);
             event.setStatus(status);
             WebResource clientResource = client.resource(pushURL);
             ClientResponse resp = clientResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, event);
        }
         if(pushMsgId != null)
             return Response.ok().entity("OK").build();
         else
             return Response.ok().entity("Error: save push notification failed").build(); 
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(PushService.class.getSimpleName()+" addPushNotification() failed on key: " + key + " \n", t);
        return Response.status(GliifWebConstants.HTTP_GLIIF_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .header("HTTP_GLIIF_SERVER_ERROR","Gliif RestFull Service addPushNotification() operation caught runtime exception on saving push message on key:"+ key).build();
    }
}
```

The code for the "Push Event" class :

```
public class PushEvent implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String eventId = "";
private String key = null; //must have
private String url = "";
private String message = "";
private Date createdDate = null;
private int status = -1;


public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getEventId() {
    return eventId;
}
public void setEventId(String eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
}
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

Now when i run this i get this error:

**A message body writer for Java type, class `com.gliif.model.PushEvent`, and MIME media type, `application/json`, was not found**

I have tried every possible way to correct this problem by going through the stackoverflow forums but i was to no avail. Can someone please help me solve this problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. turns out the jersey config was wrong. all i did was to add these lines inside the code for creating the jersey client.

```
DefaultClientConfig defaultClientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
defaultClientConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
Client client = Client.create(defaultClientConfig);
```

And the error was resolved. Thanks Chasmo for pointing me to the right direction :) .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a class in your project, which implements a MessageBodyWriter for your `PushEvent` class. This could look something like this.

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class PushEventWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<PushEvent> {

    // implement methods and serialization

}
```

In this class, you have to implement the way you will transform your PushEvent into JSON.
With the `@Provider` annotation, Jersey will find this writer and use it, if the content should be JSON (becuase of the `@Produces` annotation).

Here is a good blog post describing the process: http://programmingitch.blogspot.de/2014/03/creating-simple-jax-rs-messagebodywriter.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I created the class but it still gives me the same error

Comment: can you have a look in your logs, if jersey finds this provider?

Comment: novice question but where can i find these logs you are talking about? do you mean the server logs???

Comment: yes, the logs from your web application. if have no idea what logging framework you are using and where you write your logs.

Comment: i indeed found the log and jersey has indeed found the messagebodywriter:

**INFO: Provider classes found: class com.gliif.services.PushEventMessageBodyWriter**

But its still not working.

Comment: is it the same error output? what happens, if you change the `@Produces` to `@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)`?

Comment: anything :( , i am still stuck

Comment: Well, the error message says clear, that this was the problem. The class is now there and found by Jersey. So 2 possibilities here: 1. there must be some other issues, which is not clear unless we see the full error stack trace and 2. some configuration problems with jersey

Comment: ok. Might as well give you some config info from my pom.xml:

`Jersey Client : 1.8`
`Jersey Server : 1.8`
`Jersey Json : 1.8`

These are the dependencies which i have added in pom.xml